# Google line chart not reloading when I reload the div

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I am having issue with Google line chart API. When I reload the div, the line chart does not load again.

This is the code for line chart

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    function drawChart() {
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', 'Year');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Sales');

        data.addRows(4);


         <?php 
            //gets line chart data
            echo $join;?>


        var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, {width: 320, height: 250, title: ''});
  }

</script>

<h3>Sales History</h3>
    <table border="5" style="border-color: #3b6aa8;" >
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div id="chart_div" style="border: 1;border-color: green;"></div>
            </td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

**code used to reload the div**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {


$('#sliderform').submit(function() {

    bodyContent = $.ajax({
          url: "dashboardreload.php",
          global: false,
          type: "POST",
          data: ({year : $("#yearval").val(), month: $("#monthval").val(),day : $("#dayval").val(),
          year1 : $("#year1val").val(), month1: $("#month1val").val(),day1 : $("#day1val").val()
                    }),
          dataType: "html",
          async:false,
          success: function(msg){
           //alert('test');
          }
       }
    ).responseText;

    $('#dash').html(bodyContent);
    //confirm(bodyContent);
    return false;


    });

});
</script>
```

Comment: I am doing it with Jquery .. when a date slider is submitted.. it makes a new query and reloads the files in the div again. here is the code

Comment: I have added the reload code to the question itself

Answer (score 4, accepted):

so this might be the problem

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
```

even tho you are reloading this content the page still has these references loaded
and there might not ever be a call to drawChart on the second time around because
the google script isn't loading any new content

to get around this you might want to call the drawChart function yourself after having loaded the new content

```
success: function(msg){
   drawChart();
 }
```

maybe this will help. gl

Comment: Hello, this solution, adjusted for my case, worked for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

so im going to asume that the code

```
$('#dash').html(bodyContent);
```

is trying to reinsert the div into the page
and you are fetching a new version from the server

the #dash element is not visible in your code here but i am 
assuming its a parent tag.

and this code is trying to refetch the page

```
bodyContent = $.ajax({
      url: "dashboardreload.php",
      global: false,
      type: "POST",
      data: ({
         year : $("#yearval").val(), month: $("#monthval").val(),day : $("#dayval").val(),
      year1 : $("#year1val").val(), month1: $("#month1val").val(),day1 : $("#day1val").val()
                }),
      dataType: "html",
      async:false,
      success: function(msg){
       //alert('test');
      }
   }
).responseText;
```

first of all in javascript you define a variable like this

```
var bodyContent = .....
```

you will run in to some truble otherwise with global scope

and secondly ajax calls are async the success method you have there is what
gives you the response from the server when its rdy

```
success: function(bodyContent){
   $('#dash').html(bodyContent);
}
```

i hope this helps

Comment: Hello  ,
I have no issue with other files .. as dashboardreaload.php has many files included in it .. the only thing that does not get reloadead is google chart ..  if I echo anything else in googlechart.php file that is included in dashboardreloaded.php it is displayed.

So I think there is no issue with the jquery .google chart has some issue that I am not able to sort out till now 

THank you for your support

Comment: thanks this idea helped .. it didnt work at sucess but worked when I placed the function call after the content of the div was placed ...such a relief :)

thanks a mile